# Autologin with superuser access and run my script in Ubuntu server 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix, server

I want to achieve two things: 
1. Automatically login 
2. Running `/scripts/bootstrap.sh` after automatic login (in foreground not in background).

I tried using `/etc/systemd/system/...` and running my script as a service but it always runs in the background. I also tried running it through `/etc/rc.local` but it starts running before the login prompts which i don't want.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What do you call *automatic login*?

Comment: that the login prompt will not appear and will take the user directly to root directory with root privilege for every boot @SergeBallesta

Comment: That seems a terrible idea on a security point of view, because it means an unattended console logged as root. It can certainly be done by directly starting a shell script calling your scripts and ending with a `/bin/bash` command through `openvt` in your inittab file, but I strongly urge you not to go that way...

Comment: I am deploying my script to an IPC using Ubuntu server 16.04 environment. I am not really trying it to a real environment so you can shake off the security issues. :) Now, can you please elaborate step by step how to achieve that? Thanks!! @SergeBallesta

Comment: `inittab` doesn't exist in 16.04.2 LTS server @SergeBallesta

Comment: Sorry I have no Ubuntu system. I assume that even if inittab does not exist, it must have been replaced that *something other* that starts  the xxgetty on the system consoles. You should be able to replace one of the xxgetty with a shell or a openvt shell. IMHO, you'd better ask for that on AskUbuntu, but you should think twice of why you need that in a console...

Comment: I tried askubuntu but nothing helped whatsoever. Which is exactly why I am here. Once again, don't worry about the security issue. I am merely using the environment in a manufacturing line. So security is least of my worries. I was expecting more concrete solution but oh well. Thanks anyway. @SergeBallesta

Comment: See this ?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin

This describes the automatic login on LightDM, which I assume Ubuntu must be using then...

Why do you need login after all? Just making some kind of service script would also work probably.

Comment: I tried that one, didn't work. Also the service thing. It runs in the background. Like I said, I want my script to be running in the foreground. @Klamberext

Comment: Well, perhaps this ?

http://askubuntu.com/questions/168706/how-do-i-auto-login-as-root-into-the-tty-upon-boot

Automatic start can be done in the .bashrc file in your users(root) home directory. Just add your commands to that file. If it doesn't exist, create it.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 server doesn't have `tty1.conf` under `/etc/init/` @Klamberext. And well what should I do after creating `.bashrc`? Running a script is one thing but how can I autologin from there?

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275021

By that time I would have switched distro.

Comment: Like I said before, I tried that. It worked as a service but it runs in the background (as a service should be running) but I don't want my script to run in the background but in the foreground. @Klamberext

Answer (score 0):

/usr/share/xsessions/bootstrap.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=bootstrap
Comment=Auto start without password
Exec=xterm -e /scripts/bootstrap.sh
#Exec=xterm
Type=Application
Terminal=true
```

/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-user=user
autologin-session=bootstrap
xserver-command=X -s 0 -dpms
```